# Вывод множества дат из базы данных mysql средствами php

Tags: timestamp, php, дата, mysql

Вывожу из mysql данные типа date, скрипт пишу на php.

Выводятся даты 01.01.1970

Получилось вывести нормально дату, добавив в запрос `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TaskDateDed)`.

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ***, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TaskDateDed) AS TaskDateDed** FROM task";

<td><?php echo date('d.m.Y', $Task->TaskDateDed);?></td>-выводит нормально
<td><?php echo date("d.m.Y", $Task->TaskDateStart);?></td>-выводит 01.01.1970
```

Подскажите, как мне добавить еще переменные в `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` или как обрабатывать дату вне sql запроса?

Comment: В поле типа time хранится только время, а не дата, поэтому функция date выводит вам 1970 год, т.к вы туда передаёте только время, без даты.

Comment: Простите, ошибся, тип данных date, как же включить в UNIX_TIMESTAMP несколько переменных? Или как вне запроса обработать их? Уже отчаялся рыскать в инете...(

Comment: Пожалуйста подскажите! Я уверен тут много умных людей которые сталкивались с проблемой вывода более 1 даты!!!

Comment: @evgenuy, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведённом SQL-запросе выбираются два столбца, `TaskDateDed` и ещё какое-то `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. `TaskDateStart` взяться просто неоткуда, видимо объект `$Task` возвращает вместо несуществующего атрибута что-то, что php функция `data` интерпретирует как 0 (php любит угадывать и додумывать), ну а 0 в unixtime - это 0:00:00 первого января 1970 года (начало "эпохи Юникс").

Добавьте в запрос `TaskDateStart`. Как-то так:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ***, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TaskDateDed) AS TaskDateDed**, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TaskDateStart) AS TaskDateStart FROM task";
```

Только я не понял, что символизируют звёздочки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!! 
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS - тут не важен, сорри, что не удалил. 

ДА, ЗАРАБОТАЛО! До этого пробывал так пару раз, почему-то не срабатывало, сейчас заработало)

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Name1) AS Name1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Name2) AS Name2
без звездочек